# To count the delimiter between columns in spark RDD or DataFrame and move the rows to separate RDD or dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark programming and I am loading multiple TSV.gz files into RDD or Dataframes. I want to count the number of tabs between columns once loaded and move the rows of data to separate RDD or dataframes based on the below condition.

Total number of  columns = 996

```
If the number of tab counts = 995 -> move to another RDD or DF
If the number of tab counts < 995 -> move to another RDD or DF
If the number of tab counts > 995 -> move to another RDD or DF
```

I tried the below but was returning Boolean values

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("/abc/*.tsv.gz")
textFile.map(line=>line.split("\t"))
val file1 = textFile.filter(line => line.contains("\t").count() > 995)
val file2 = textFile.filter(line => line.contains("\t").count() < 995)
```

Please let me know if the same can be achieved

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

First of all since Spark 2.0 it is highly recommended to stick to SparkSQL unless you require some low-level access to RDDs. It is not your case so feel free to forget RDDs for a bit while you're learning.

What you are trying to achieve can be done several ways. Assume the TSV has a header row or you can assign names to the column. Leverage the CSV format reader and just use `\t` as a separator:

```
val all = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("file.tsv")
```

Next assume `left` is a name of a column 994, `center` is name of a column 995 and `right` is a name of a column 996.

```
val left = all.filter(col("center").isNull)
val center = all.filter(col("center").isNotNull && col("right").isNull)
val right = all.filter(col("right").isNotNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is csv, always use dataframes. You can make use of df.columns.length which gives the number of columns in a csv file.
Here is a sample code for a csv file with 8 columns. You can modify accordingly for 996 columns.

Content of emp1.csv

```
7369     "SMITH"     "CLERK"     7902    "17-Dec-80"     800     20  10
7499     "ALLEN"     "SALESMAN"  7698    "20-Feb-81"     1600    300     30
```

Spark code

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
object StackOverflow {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Testing..").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val emp1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","\t").load("in/emp1.csv")
    emp1.show(false)
    val col_len = emp1.columns.length
    if(col_len == 8) {
      val df1 = emp1.toDF("empno", "ename", "job", "mgr", "hiredate", "sal", "comm", "deptno")
      df1.show(false)
    }
    if(col_len== 7) {
      val df2 = emp1.toDF("empno", "ename", "job", "mgr", "hiredate", "sal", "comm")
      df2.show(false)
    }

  }
}
```